# Match substring with special characters in a string

Tags: php, regex

I ran into a regex challenge and so far couldn't figure out the solution.

I have a string for example like this:

```
&str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce malesuada sit amet risus vel ultricies. Quisque pretium leo in sem sodales, in ullamcorper dolor aliquet. Duis at massa felis. Pellentesque fringilla **'![bibendum auctor]**. Nunc scelerisque aliquam sem. Nam pharetra eros quis libero molestie iaculis. Etiam vehicula blandit ipsum in sodales. Nulla tempus cursus lacus, sed cursus ligula consequat at. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse at blandit" ipsum, sed porta urna. Vesti&&&&bulum turpis risus, ultricies at sapien id, vehicula venenatis neque.";
```

And I would like to `preg_match`only this part: `preg_match(/'![bibendum auctor]/);`
As you can see, there are some special characters inside the string and this fails regexp to match the query.

I cannot use `preg_quote()`, as I don't want to escape the special characters at other parts of the whole string.

Comment: `preg_quote('![bibendum auctor]', '/')` wouldn't touch the rest of the string?

Comment: You can escape characters using an inverted dash, for example `\'\!\[bibendum auctor]`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that the special characters are unknown, randomly generated thus I cannot manually escape them. The best would be I could match this for example: fringilla '![bibendum auctor]. Nunc

Comment: Like:  preg_match(/fringilla.*Nunc/)

Comment: That isn't valid PHP syntax at all.

Comment: Yes, just noting that any character can appear.

Answer (score 1):

You can match anything in square brackets preceded by exclamation mark like this:

```
/!\[([^\]]+)\]/
```

[working example](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/5kx)

**edit:** if you want to match the exact phrase as you've tried you have to escape the brackets like thi:

```
/'!\[bibendum auctor\]/
```

[example](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/5ky)

Comment: Thanks but the square brackets were only example of special characters. The part to be matched can be anything, for instance: '!]bibendum auctor[$

Comment: @Nick it will work with anything, you just have to escape the [special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

Comment: The problem is that in the whole string only this part is known: **fringilla.*Nunc** I need to match what's between these two, and this substring has random characters; some what cause the regex fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_quote` on the string you are searching for like this:

```
$str = <<<EOT
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce malesuada sit amet risus vel ultricies. Quisque pretium leo in sem sodales, in ullamcorper dolor aliquet. Duis at massa felis. Pellentesque fringilla **'![bibendum auctor]**. Nunc scelerisque aliquam sem. Nam pharetra eros quis libero molestie iaculis. Etiam vehicula blandit ipsum in sodales. Nulla tempus cursus lacus, sed cursus ligula consequat at. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse at blandit" ipsum, sed porta urna. Vesti&&&&bulum turpis risus, ultricies at sapien id, vehicula venenatis neque.
EOT;

$search = preg_quote('![bibendum auctor]', '/');

preg_match("/$search/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => ![bibendum auctor] )
```

(In case you're wondering the `<<<EOT` is [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) - I just used it so I didn't have to escape all the quotes in the string)